# Which other languages pronounce <j> as [dʒ]

Tags: phonetics, orthography, list-of-languages, writing-systems, sociophonetics

[On a related question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8730/how-is-it-that-such-varied-sounds-in-major-european-languages-came-to-be-repre), the OP points out that the grapheme `j` has a variety of pronunciations throughout various languages: as [ʒ] in French, [j] in German, and [x] in Spanish. Does any other language pronounce  using the voiced postalveolar affricate [dʒ]?

Comment: Are you asking about spelling or about phonology?

Comment: Phonetics, I think. I want to know which languages articulate the grapheme j using the voiced postalveolar affricate.

Comment: I think you are asking which scripts use the grapheme "j" to represent the phoneme [dʒ]. That is a question about orthography, not phonetics.

Comment: Surely they're two sides of the same coin. I'm either asking which writing systems write [dʒ] as j, or which phonologies pronounce j as [dʒ].

Comment: No, they're not two sides of the same coin. A language may have several different orthographies, or none, without affecting its phonology (or phonetics). I suspect @fdb is pressing the point, as I would, because non-specialists often confuse a language with its script.

Answer (score 2):

'J' stands for /dʒ/ in Indonesian, Somali, Malay, Igbo, Shona, Oromo, Turkmen, and Zulu.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J

Comment: All, of course, in imitation of English spelling. Until recently Indonesian used "dj" for [dʒ], following Dutch orthography, before adopting the English-based orthography of Malay.

Comment: @fdb -Yes, but the question was about the names of languages, so here they are.

Comment: Are you suggesting that [dʒ] was an English "invention", @fdb? If you're willing to provide more context on this, it would make a great answer.

Comment: Where did I say it was an English invention?

Comment: You didn't, but you said that each of the languages Yellow Sky listed were derived or imitated from English. I inferred from this that English first mapped j -> [dʒ], and some other languages derived this.

Comment: In the standard Roman transliteration of Sanskrit, Hindi, and other Indian languages, **J** is used for the letter **ज** (and its variant allographs in different Indian abugidas), which represents the palatal affricate /tʃ/. India and Malaysia were British colonies, and English spelling conventions are widespread.

Comment: Are you sure of that, John? I thought it generally represented a voiced palatal.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake; /dʒ/ is the voiced palatal represented by **ज**. Thanks, @Colin.

Comment: What language distinguishes [ʒ] from [ʑ]? If none, then Hepburn romanization of Japanese uses <j> for [dʑ] in imitation of English.

Comment: @tepples - Russian distinguishes [ʑ] from [ʒ:].

Comment: @ Leo King: The use of j for [dʒ], like the use of ch for [tʃ], was not original to English; English took this spelling convention from French, which used to have the sounds [tʃ] and [dʒ].

Answer (score 1):

In some Romanizations of Armenian, "**j**" is used for the letter ջ, which is pronounced [dʒ] in Eastern Armenian, or for ճ, pronounced [dʒ] in Western.

These Armenian letters are also sometimes transcribed (especially in older texts) using "**j^**", i.e., "j" with a hachek instead of a dot. In this case, the regular "j" (with a dot) would be used for the sound [dz], as represented by ձ in Eastern and ծ in Western. (Incidentally, I don't know of any other case where "j" has been used to represent [dz], but for some reason it was chosen in this case.)